# Clearing Markers from Google Direction Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Google Direction Service to retrieve the lat+lng of the route, then pass the latlon to a php file and return markers via a xml file.

This all works fine, apart from I cant clear the old markers when I request a new route. The code below shows how I get the markers from the xml file, using jQuery. And the code underneath that shows the function I'm trying to use to clear the route (that works) and the old markers (that does not!)

Many thanks for any help.

```
//RETURN DATA FOR PLACE MARKERS
jQuery.get("MYXMLFILE", function(data) {
    jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
        var eachMarker = jQuery(this);
        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Lat").text()),
            parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Lng").text())
        );
        var header  = eachMarker.find("title").text();
        var content = eachMarker.find("Content").text();
        var wxicon  = eachMarker.find("icon").text();
        //---------------------------------------------
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            map: map,
            icon: wxicon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: header,
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker); // store the reference
    });
});

//CLEAR OLD ROUTE + CLEAR MARKERS

function deleteOverlays() {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
    gmarker.setMap(null);
    gmarkers = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var markersArray = [];
```

Every time your create a marker add it to `markerArray`

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

   marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            icon: icoImg,
            map: map,
            shadow: flagIcon_shadow,
            title: locations[i][0]
    });
    markersArray.push(marker[i]);
}
```

After call deleteOverlays() to delete all maker from map.

```
    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
   function deleteOverlays() {
       if (markersArray) {
           for (i in markersArray) {
              markersArray[i].setMap(null);
           }
           markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }
```

in your case use this

```
function deleteOverlays() {
   if (gmarkers) {
           for (i in gmarkers) {
               gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
           }
       gmarkers.length = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, where do you get the locations.length from for the loop?

Comment: ^if this is the answer for your problem please mark as answer :)

Comment: I will once i have got it working! - I added your loop, and it didn't display anything!

Comment: I think the trouble I'm having, is adding the markers to the markerarray

Comment: `gmarkers` must be a global, please define it as `var gmarkers = [];` top of the code

Comment: Still struggling where to add your loop to add markers to the array

Comment: Hi, I have kind of fixed it, I haven't got your function to clear the markers working, but I have found another solution to change the xml file request based on the users route. So its all good. Thanks for replying thou..:-0

Comment: could you mark up my question please as i only have 6 points :-( so I cant rate your answer... Ta.